# sum two numbers and than multiply with another using php and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to add two numbers than multiply with another number whenever a keyup happens in the textboxes of those three numbers. I am trying to do this using php and ajax. My addition code is these:

My html code:

```
<form method="post">
  adult <input type="date" name="adult" id="adult" class="counter">
  child <input type="date" name="child" id="child" class="counter">
  amount <input type="date" name="amount" id="amount" class="counter">
</form>
<div id="showTotal"></div>
```

My jquery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".counter").on('change keyup paste', function(e)
  {
   var number =
    {
        numad:$("#adult").val(),
        numch:$("#child").val(),
        numamo:$("#amount").val(),
        is_ajax:1
    };
    $.ajax(
    {
       type:"post",
       url:"process.php",
       data: number,
       dataType:"json",
       success:function(counter)
       {
           $("#showTotal").html(counter);
       }
    });
    return false;
   });
  });
```

process.php page:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST["numad"],$_POST["numch"],$_POST["numamo"]))
 {
   $adultnum = $_POST["numad"];
   $childnum = $_POST["numch"];
   $amountnum = $_POST["numamo"];

   $addtotal = $adultnum + $childnum * $amountnum;
   echo json_encode($addtotal);
 }

?>
```

This code id not working

Comment: Is there a reason you're sending the values to PHP to do the calculation? Frankly it seems completely pointless as you can perform the logic in JS immediately, without waiting for a request to complete.

Comment: Why not just calculate it using javascript?

Comment: `numamo:$("#amount").val` should be `numamo:$("#amount").val()`

Comment: oh sorry!! its my typing mistake. niza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip PHP and do it with JavaScript only:

```
.....
var total = $("#adult").val() + $("#child").val() * $("#amount").val();
$("#showTotal").html(parseInt(total));
.....
```